# How to change the "accept" value of input file on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

The scenario is that I need to select which type of file I need to upload. After I have selected a file type (e.g `XML`) the file upload dialog box will open and filter the types of the file selected to `XML` only. Same goes to the other options in the radio buttons. I need to get the values selected in the radio button to be placed on the "accept" property of the file upload. Is there a way to achieve this?

HTML code here

```
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="xml" value="xml" />XML<br />
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="html" value="html" />HTML<br />
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="json" value="json" />JSON<br />

<span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary">Browse<input type="file" id="ImportFile" accept=".xml" data-bind="event: { change: $root.Browse }"></span>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a  `.change()` event on the radio buttons, and set the value of the input after. To set the value of the "accept" use `.attr()` like `.attr("accept", "." + $(this).val())`

```js
$('.selectfileclass').change(function() {
  $('#ImportFile').attr("accept", "." + $(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="xml" value="xml" />XML<br />
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="html" value="html" />HTML<br />
<input type="radio" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="json" value="json" />JSON<br />

<span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary">Browse<input type="file" id="ImportFile" accept=".xml" data-bind="event: { change: $root.Browse }"></span>
```

If you want to select multiple parameters, you would have to use a checkbox and not radio.

```js
$('.selectfileclass').click(function() {
  var s = $('.selectfileclass:checked').map(function() {
    return "." + $(this).val()
  }).get().join(",")
  console.log(s)
  $('#ImportFile').attr("accept", "." + s)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="xml" value="xml" />XML<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="html" value="html" />HTML<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectfileclass" name="file" id="json" value="json" />JSON<br />

<span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary">Browse<input type="file" id="ImportFile" accept=".xml" data-bind="event: { change: $root.Browse }"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try live event for that For E.g

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function() {
  $('#ImportFile').attr("accept", "." + $(this).val())
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```